# histogram of letter grades

Tags: r

I am trying to make a histogram of grades. Here are my variables.

```
> grade <- factor(c("A","A","A","B","A","A","A","A","B","A","C","B","B","B"))
> numberBook <- c(53,42,40,40,39,34,34,30,28,24,22,21,20,16)
```

But when I plot it, I get an error message.

```
> hist(numberBook~grade)
Error in hist.default(numberBook ~ grade) : 'x' must be numeric
```

What can I do?

Comment: You can read the manual.  `hist` does not accept a formula.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're imagining with both `grade` and `numberBook` in the plot. `hist(numberBook)` works, or `plot(grade)`, or `barplot(prop.table(table(grade)))`?

Comment: Or perhaps `barplot(numberBook, names.arg = grade)` ? Unlike the examples in the other comments, this one uses both the vectors. A picture (made in excel, or even paint) would help us know what you're after

Comment: yes barplot is what I need thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've got multiple letters so I've guessed that you want a total of all the A, B and Cs. This may not be quite right. I've recreated your data like this using rep and summing the counts of grades (could be wrong)

```
data <-c(rep("A",(53+42+40+34+34+30+28+22)), rep("B",(39+24+20+16+22)),rep("C",22))
```

Then I can plot the data using barplot:

```
barplot(prop.table(table(data)))
```

Barplot is probably what you want here.